# KRecorder's preview function doesn't work in red5 localhost

Tags: flash, red5, recorder, kaltura

I install red5 server in localhost, then use a recorder widget - [KRecorder](http://www.kaltura.org/project/video_record_flash_widget), it work well but when I change the rtmphost from "rtmp://www.kaltura.com" to "rtmp://localhost", the preview function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By preview you mean a thumnail of the video that is displayed in the player? Red5 does not automatically produce any thumbnails of recordings. You would need to code something in red5 that generates thumbs from recordings. For example with a FFMPEG task.

Sebastian